# Why do we indicate current to be flowing against electrons in a electric circuit ? If it is a convention thenwhy do we draw it along studying it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, charge, electric-current, conventions

I believe that electric current is a kind of force (even when we consider it to be opposite to the flow of electrons). If it is so then what is the nature of this force ? And also tell me if there are energy carriers in that constitute this force.

Comment: electric current is a flow that we can measure; it cannot be a force. The convention of electric current being opposite to the flow of electrons is a rather unfortunate event of history and it is a human problem, that we have collectively ignored the change.

Comment: When we use the word ‘measurement’ we shall be implying that current is a quantity and only a calculative unit created to study physical changes or properties but when we assign the word ‘flow’ to the same thing, it is equivalent to describing a phenomenon. Please explain how the words ‘flow’ and ‘measurement’ fit together ?

Comment: What you are thinking is just wrong. If we are being insanely pedantic, it is possible to make a measurement device that counts, one by one, the electrons flowing through a vacuum chamber. That will also determine its electric current.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to say (if possible please give an answer). For your most recent comment, I would like to say that it is not clear what you’re trying to convey and the comment seems a bit out-of-context or in clear words I feel like you are drifting away from the topic. It would also be better if you provide me with an analogy on what you are trying to tell me in your next submission. (strongly hoping that it will come)

Comment: Also please try to lower your answer levels down to a grade schooler’s level because I just passed grade school.

Comment: You also said that I am thinking wrong so please try to rectify that perspective of mine. I am also not certain about what about my query did you find wrong. (If it was the flow and measurement thing I can’t think of a way I can be wrong.

Comment: Electric current is not a force.

Comment: I can't understand your question, "why do we draw it along studying it?" Can you rephrase to make it more clear what you're asking?

Comment: Frankly, if you have just finished grade school then you should be asking what electric current is and not stating that it is a force. This is a bad starting point and it is not worth asking follow-up clarification from the false starting point. Just discard that idea and start over with a more open mind.

Comment: I understand, my question was not described clearly. Sorry. So, I was trying to say that in a circuit we show the direction of current to be opposite to the direction of the flow of electrons by arrows embedded in the traces in a circuit like in the image provided here : https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=558148111&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIN1027IN1029&hl=en-GB&sxsrf=AB5stBjOul7_DScnxOVtZ7WYhusJcuGpzA:1692375509873&q=arrow+indicating+current&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQoN6IzuaAAxVca2wGHfDWCB0Q0pQJegQIDRAB&biw=1194&bih=715&dpr=2#imgrc=f5Kfbsj7RStsLM.

Comment: I don’t know if the practice I am referring to is region-based, level-based, domain-based or if it is particular to some education systems or only one.

Comment: @Dale
Sir, some circumstances persuaded me to do so. But at this point, it is just impossible for me to dispose this thought off my mind.

Comment: Furthermore, I am beginning to think that conventional current or the current which I mentioned in the question which is opposite to the flow of electrons is actually not a force but it is still what drives electrons towards the positive terminal.

Answer (score 4):

> I believe that electric current is a kind of force

The word *force* has a very specific meaning in physics. Electric current is not a force.

A force is the phenomenon by which can objects accelerated.

For example, if I push you with my hand, you feel a force. But the force isn't my hand, and it isn't your body. It's not an object at all.  It's the "push" itself, not any of the individual objects involved in the push.

Some phenomena in physics produce forces, but the forces are considered as their own thing, separate from the objects that produce them. For example, the Earth produces gravity, which produces a force on you that keeps you from floating off the ground. But that doesn't mean that the Earth is a force.

Similarly, an electric current can produce a force through magnetism on a moving charge or a current-carrying wire. The current can be the source of a force. But that doesn't mean that the current **is** a force.